# DashTable not updating with DatePickerSingle input in Callback

Tags: python, callback, datepicker, plotly-dash

I am pretty new to dash and I have tried to read as much as I can to understand what the issue might be. In a nutshell I have a single datepicker which is an input to the DataTable and Graph callback. The graph callback is working fine so it is just the DataTable which is causing problems. I also tried the single input to multiple output callback but didnt work. My code is as below:

```
app = JupyterDash()

folder = os.getcwd()
portfolio_returns_table = pd.read_csv(Path(folder, 'portfolioreturns_maria.csv',parse_dates=[0]))
portfolio_returns_table = portfolio_returns_table.set_index('Unnamed: 0')
name_portfolioID_table = pd.read_csv(Path(folder, 'name_portfolioID.csv'))

#Calculate portfolio cumulative returns
df_cumret = (portfolio_returns_table+1).cumprod().round(5)

df_cumret.index = pd.to_datetime(df_cumret.index)

app.layout = html.Div(html.Div([dcc.DatePickerSingle(
    id='my-date-picker-single',
    min_date_allowed=dt.date(df_cumret.index.min()),
    max_date_allowed=dt.date(df_cumret.index.max()),
    initial_visible_month=dt.date(df_cumret.index.max()),
    date = dt.date(df_cumret.index.max())
,display_format = 'Y-MM-DD',clearable = True), 
html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-single'),
html.Div(dash_table.DataTable(id = 'data_table',
data = {},
fixed_rows={'headers': True},
style_cell = {'textAlign': 'left'},
style_table={'height': 400})), 
html.Div(dcc.Graph('my_graph'))
                        
]))

@app.callback([Output('data_table','data'),Output('data_table','columns')], 
[Input('my-date-picker- 
single','date')])    
def update_leader_table(date):

  #Get data for the selected date and transpose
  df_T = df_cumret.loc[[date]].T

  #Sort the table to reveal the top leaders
  df_Top = df_T.sort_values(df_T.columns[0], ascending=False)[:10]

  #Convert the index to an interger
  df_Top.index = df_Top.index.astype(int)

  #Generate the leaderboard to given date
  df_leader = pd.merge(df_Top,name_portfolioID_table, 
  left_index=True,right_index=True, how = 'left')

  #Create the col rank
  df_leader['Rank'] = range(1,len(df_leader)+1)

  df_leader.columns = ['Cum Return', 'Investor','Rank']

  df_leader.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)


  data = df_leader.to_dict('records')
  columns= [{'id': c, 'name': c, "selectable": True} for c in 
  df_leader.columns]

  return (data,columns)

 #callback to link calendar to graph
@app.callback(Output('my_graph','figure'),[Input('my-date-picker-single','date')])
def update_graph(date):
  #date filter
  df_T = df_cumret.loc[:date].T

   #Sort the table to reveal the top leaders & filter for leaderboard
   df_Top = df_T.sort_values(df_T.columns[-1], ascending=False)[:10]

   #Transpose to have date as index
   df_top_graph = df_Top.T

   #set the columns as an Int
   df_top_graph.columns = df_top_graph.columns.astype(int)

   #Rename columns
   df_top_graph.rename(columns=dict(zip(name_portfolioID_table.index, 
   name_portfolioID_table.name)), 
   inplace=True)

   #Generate graph
   fig = px.line(df_top_graph, x = df_top_graph.index, y = 
   df_top_graph.columns, title='ETF LEADERBOARD PERFORMANCE: '+date, labels= 
   {'Unnamed: 0':'Date','value':'Cumulative Returns'})

   fig.update_layout(hovermode = 'x unified')
   fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Return: %{y} <br>Date: %{x}')
   fig.update_layout(legend_title_text = 'Investor')

   return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run_server(mode = 'inline',debug=True, port = 65398)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please fix the formatting of your code block (consult [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). As you can see the indentation isn't appropriate and there other errors. I tried to fix it but got lost and don't have the time to do it.

Comment: @Timus thanks for the feedback, I have indented the code correctly now, hope it looks better, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey, your code is a little long and makes use of data that other people don't have, so it's going to be hard for others to debug your code. I'd suggest trying to create a minimal 
 working example, that someone can copy and paste and try themselves. You could gradually remove parts of your code until you have just a small layout skeleton and a single callback targeting the `data` and `column` properties, using a DataFrame with dummy data. Also, by the time you get there, it's quite possible that you might have found your bug!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @nedned, I did find the bug eventually which was not converting the date from the datepicker to a datetime object in the callback. Didnt know that the date is passed as a string.